# Не работает воспроизведение плейлиста из базы данных

Tags: sql, pyqt5

Вот код файла main.py

```
import sys
import os
import sqlite3  # Добавлен импорт модуля sqlite3
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QFileDialog, QSlider, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QComboBox, QInputDialog
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap, QImage, QImageReader
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QUrl
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaContent, QMediaPlayer
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaContent, QMediaPlayer, QMediaPlaylist
from mutagen.id3 import ID3, APIC
from PIL import Image
import io
from playlist_manager import PlaylistManager

class AudioPlayer(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.playlist_manager = PlaylistManager('myplaylist.db')  # Передаем только имя базы данных
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        widget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

        main_layout = QHBoxLayout()

        left_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addLayout(left_layout)

        right_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addLayout(right_layout)

        self.album_cover_label = QLabel(self)
        self.album_cover_label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        left_layout.addWidget(self.album_cover_label)

        select_file_button = QPushButton('Выбрать файл', self)
        select_file_button.setObjectName("select_file_button")
        select_file_button.clicked.connect(self.open_file_dialog)
        left_layout.addWidget(select_file_button)

        self.playlist_combo_box = QComboBox(self)
        self.playlist_combo_box.setObjectName("playlist_combo_box")
        self.playlist_combo_box.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.load_playlist)
        right_layout.addWidget(self.playlist_combo_box)
        self.update_playlist_combo_box()

        add_to_playlist_button = QPushButton('Добавить в плейлист', self)
        add_to_playlist_button.setObjectName("add_to_playlist_button")
        add_to_playlist_button.clicked.connect(self.add_to_playlist)
        right_layout.addWidget(add_to_playlist_button)

        remove_from_playlist_button = QPushButton('Удалить из плейлиста', self)
        remove_from_playlist_button.setObjectName("remove_from_playlist_button")
        remove_from_playlist_button.clicked.connect(self.remove_from_playlist)
        right_layout.addWidget(remove_from_playlist_button)

        create_playlist_button = QPushButton('Создать плейлист', self)
        create_playlist_button.setObjectName("create_playlist_button")
        create_playlist_button.clicked.connect(self.create_playlist)
        right_layout.addWidget(create_playlist_button)

        play_playlist_button = QPushButton('Включить плейлист', self)
        play_playlist_button.setObjectName("play_playlist_button")
        play_playlist_button.clicked.connect(self.play_playlist)
        right_layout.addWidget(play_playlist_button)

        slider_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        left_layout.addLayout(slider_layout)

        self.current_time_label = QLabel(self)
        self.current_time_label.setObjectName("current_time_label")
        slider_layout.addWidget(self.current_time_label)

        self.seek_slider = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal, self)
        self.seek_slider.setObjectName("seek_slider")
        self.seek_slider.sliderMoved.connect(self.set_position)
        slider_layout.addWidget(self.seek_slider)

        self.total_length_label = QLabel(self)
        self.total_length_label.setObjectName("total_length_label")
        slider_layout.addWidget(self.total_length_label)

        controls_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        left_layout.addLayout(controls_layout)

        self.play_pause_button = QPushButton('', self)
        self.play_pause_button.setObjectName("play_pause_button")
        self.play_pause_button.clicked.connect(self.toggle_play_pause)
        self.play_pause_button.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {border: none;}")
        controls_layout.addWidget(self.play_pause_button)

        self.media_player = QMediaPlayer()
        self.media_player.positionChanged.connect(self.update_slider)
        self.media_player.durationChanged.connect(self.update_duration)
        self.media_player.error.connect(self.handle_error)

        self.volume_slider = QSlider(Qt.Vertical, self)
        self.volume_slider.setObjectName("volume_slider")
        self.volume_slider.setRange(0, 100)
        self.volume_slider.setValue(100)
        self.volume_slider.valueChanged.connect(self.set_volume)
        right_layout.addWidget(self.volume_slider, alignment=Qt.AlignBottom)

        self.seek_slider.setStyleSheet("""
            QSlider::groove:horizontal {
                border: 1px solid #bbb;
                background: white;
                height: 10px;
                border-radius: 4px;
            }
            QSlider::sub-page:horizontal {
                background: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 1, y2: 0, stop: 0 #66e, stop: 1 #548);
                height: 10px;
                border-radius: 4px;
            }
            QSlider::handle:horizontal {
                background: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1, stop:0 #eee, stop:1 #ccc);
                border: 1px solid #777;
                width: 13px;
                margin-top: -2px;
                margin-bottom: -2px;
                border-radius: 4px;
            }
        """)

        self.volume_slider.setStyleSheet("""
            QSlider::groove:vertical {
                background: white;
                width: 10px;
            }
            QSlider::handle:vertical {
                background: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1, stop:0 #eee, stop:1 #ccc);
                border: 1px solid #777;
                height: 13px;
                margin-left: -2px;
                margin-right: -2px;
                border-radius: 4px;
            }
            QSlider::add-page:vertical {
                background: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 #66e, stop: 1 #548);
                width: 10px;
                border-radius: 4px;
            }
        """)

        widget.setLayout(main_layout)
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 500, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('Audio Player')
        self.show()

        # Подключаем CSS файл
        with open('styles.css', 'r') as file:
            self.setStyleSheet(file.read())

    def toggle_play_pause(self):
        if self.media_player.state() == QMediaPlayer.PlayingState:
            self.pause_music()
        else:
            self.play_music()

    def play_music(self):
        self.media_player.play()
        self.play_pause_button.setIcon(QIcon('icons/pause.png'))

    def pause_music(self):
        self.media_player.pause()
        self.play_pause_button.setIcon(QIcon('icons/play.png'))

    def open_file_dialog(self):
        # Открытие диалогового окна для выбора аудио файла
        file_name, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open File', os.getenv('HOME'))

        # Загрузка выбранного аудио файла в QMediaPlayer
        if file_name:
            self.media_player.setMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl.fromLocalFile(file_name)))
            self.album_cover_label.setText(os.path.basename(file_name))

            # Установка максимального значения ползунка перемотки
            self.media_player.mediaStatusChanged.connect(self.configure_slider)

    def update_slider(self, position):
        self.seek_slider.setValue(position)
        self.current_time_label.setText(self.format_time(position))

    def update_duration(self, duration):
        self.seek_slider.setRange(0, duration)
        self.total_length_label.setText(self.format_time(duration))

    def format_time(self, milliseconds):
        seconds = milliseconds // 1000
        minutes, seconds = divmod(seconds, 60)
        hours, minutes = divmod(minutes, 60)
        if hours > 0:
            return f"{hours:02d}:{minutes:02d}:{seconds:02d}"
        else:
            return f"{minutes:02d}:{seconds:02d}"

    def set_position(self, position):
        self.media_player.setPosition(position)

    def configure_slider(self, status):
        if status == QMediaPlayer.LoadedMedia:
            self.seek_slider.setRange(0, self.media_player.duration())

    def set_volume(self, volume):
        self.media_player.setVolume(volume)

    def handle_error(self):
        print("Error:", self.media_player.errorString())

    def load_playlist(self):
        playlist_name = self.playlist_combo_box.currentText()

        if self.playlist_manager.playlist_exists(playlist_name):
            self.playlist_manager.open_playlist(playlist_name)

            playlist = QMediaPlaylist()
            for song_path in self.playlist_manager.get_playlist(playlist_name):
                media_content = QMediaContent(QUrl.fromLocalFile(song_path))
                playlist.addMedia(media_content)

            self.media_player.setPlaylist(playlist)  # Установите плейлист в QMediaPlayer
            self.play_music()  # Начните воспроизведение

    def add_to_playlist(self):
        file_name, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Add to Playlist', os.getenv('HOME'))
        if file_name:
            self.playlist_manager.add_to_playlist(self.playlist_combo_box.currentText(), file_name)

    def remove_from_playlist(self):
        selected_items = self.playlist_combo_box.selectedItems()
        if selected_items:
            for item in selected_items:
                song_name = item.text()
                self.playlist_manager.remove_song_from_playlist(song_name)

    def create_playlist(self):
        playlist_name, ok = QInputDialog.getText(self, 'Create Playlist', 'Enter playlist name:')
        if ok and playlist_name:
            self.playlist_manager.create_playlist(playlist_name)
            self.update_playlist_combo_box()

    def update_playlist_combo_box(self):
        self.playlist_combo_box.clear()
        playlists = self.playlist_manager.get_all_playlists()
        self.playlist_combo_box.addItems(playlists)

    def play_playlist(self):
        playlist_name = self.playlist_combo_box.currentText()  # Получаем имя текущего выбранного плейлиста

        if not playlist_name:
            print("Ошибка: Плейлист не выбран")
            return

        playlist = QMediaPlaylist()
        for song_path in self.playlist_manager.get_playlist(playlist_name):
            media_content = QMediaContent(QUrl.fromLocalFile(song_path))
            playlist.addMedia(media_content)

        if not playlist.isEmpty():
            self.media_player.setPlaylist(playlist)
            self.media_player.play()
        else:
            print("Ошибка: Плейлист пуст")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = AudioPlayer()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Вот код файла playlist_manager.py

```
import sqlite3
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaPlaylist, QMediaContent


class PlaylistManager:
    def __init__(self, db_name):
        self.db_name = db_name
        self.playlists = {}
        self.initialize_database()
        self.get_all_playlists()  # Вызываем метод напрямую
        self.current_playlist = None  # Добавляем атрибут current_playlist

    def initialize_database(self):
        try:
            conn = sqlite3.connect(self.db_name)
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS playlists (name TEXT, tracks TEXT)")
            conn.commit()
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error initializing database: {str(e)}")
        finally:
            conn.close()

    def playlist_exists(self, playlist_name):
        return playlist_name in self.playlists

    def create_playlist(self, name):
        if name not in self.playlists:
            self.playlists[name] = []
            self.save_playlists()  # Сохранение после создания
            self.current_playlist = name  # Устанавливаем текущий плейлист

    def add_to_playlist(self, playlist_name, audio_file):
        if playlist_name in self.playlists:
            self.playlists[playlist_name].append(audio_file)
            self.save_playlists()  # Сохранение после добавления трека

    def remove_from_playlist(self):
        # Получите имя плейлиста из QComboBox
        selected_playlist = self.playlist_combo_box.currentText()

        # Далее, вы можете использовать selected_playlist для удаления треков
        # из выбранного плейлиста и сохранения изменений в базе данных.


    def get_playlist(self, playlist_name):
        # Получаем плейлист из словаря
        return self.playlists.get(playlist_name, [])
    
    def play_playlist(self):
        if not self.current_playlist:
            print("Ошибка: Плейлист не выбран")
            return

        playlist = QMediaPlaylist()
    
        for song_path in self.playlists[self.current_playlist]:
            media_content = QMediaContent(QUrl.fromLocalFile(song_path))
            playlist.addMedia(media_content)
    
        if not playlist.isEmpty():
            self.media_player.setPlaylist(playlist)
            self.media_player.play()
        else:
            print("Ошибка: Плейлист пуст")

    def load_playlist(self):
        playlist_name = self.playlist_combo_box.currentText()
    
        # Проверяем, существует ли плейлист с указанным именем
        if self.playlist_exists(playlist_name):
            self.open_playlist(playlist_name)
        else:
            # Если плейлист не существует, выводим сообщение об ошибке
            self.album_cover_label.setText("Ошибка: Плейлист не существует")

    def get_all_playlists(self):
        conn = sqlite3.connect(self.db_name)
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute('SELECT name FROM playlists')
        playlists = [row[0] for row in cursor.fetchall()]
        conn.close()
        # Вместо вызова update_playlist_combo_box() обновите комбобокс в вашем пользовательском интерфейсе
        # Например: self.my_ui.update_playlist_combo_box(playlists)
        return playlists

    def save_playlists(self):
        try:
            conn = sqlite3.connect(self.db_name)
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS playlists (name TEXT, tracks TEXT)")

            for name, tracks in self.playlists.items():
                cursor.execute("REPLACE INTO playlists (name, tracks) VALUES (?, ?)", (name, ",".join(tracks)))

            conn.commit()
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error saving playlists: {str(e)}")
        finally:
            conn.close()

    def open_playlist(self, playlist_name):
        if playlist_name in self.playlists:
            self.current_playlist = playlist_name
            self.play_playlist()        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    playlist_manager = PlaylistManager('myplaylist.db')
```

И в целом о проблеме есть база данных в той же папке с файлами

В эту базу данных сохроняются плейлисты в первый столбик название плейлиста, во второй путь к файлам мп3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но при включении программы (Это мп3 плеер) Выбираю плейлист любой пробовал, в консоль выводиться вот что

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Плейлист пуст хотя в базе данных указаны пути к файлам, я не могу понять в чём проблема

Comment: уточните проблему. "не работает" - увы не описание проблемы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не исключаю, что это не единственный вид ошибок у вас. Но уж что нашёл касательно `playlists`:

```py
    def get_all_playlists(self):
        ...
        playlists = [row[0] for row in cursor.fetchall()]
        ^^^^^^^^^

    def update_playlist_combo_box(self):
        ...
        playlists = self.playlist_manager.get_all_playlists()
        ^^^^^^^^^
```

Вы записываете полученные плейлисты в **локальную переменную** `playlists`, которая потом **никак не используется**. А нужно записывать результаты в **переменную экземпляра класса** `self.playlists`, которая дальше используется в методах вашего класса:

```py
    def get_all_playlists(self):
        ...
        self.playlists = [row[0] for row in cursor.fetchall()]
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    def update_playlist_combo_box(self):
        ...
        self.playlists = self.playlist_manager.get_all_playlists()
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```